# Codeigniter Message: Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to query the db with the following query in the model:

```
function showSpecific(){

    $all = $this->session->all_userdata();
    $name = $all['u_name'];

    $id = $this->db
    ->select('u_id')
    ->from('users')
    ->where('u_name', $name)
    ->get()
    ->row(); 

    $id = $id->u_id; 

    $data = $this->db->query("SELECT messages.m_id, messages.post_id, messages.m_betreff, messages.an_user, messages.von_user, messages.m_time, users.u_id, users.u_name, posts.p_titel, users.u_id, messages.m_content
                FROM messages
                INNER JOIN users 
                ON messages.von_user=users.u_id
                INNER JOIN posts
                ON messages.post_id=posts.post_id
                WHERE messages.an_user='$id'
                ORDER BY messages.m_time DESC");




    return $data;
}
```

But when I try to output the result in the view:

```
<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>';
                    echo anchor('users/showUser/'.$row->u_id, $row->u_name);
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo $row->m_betreff;
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo $row->m_content;
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo anchor('posts/showSpecific/'.$row->post_id, $row->p_titel);
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo $row->m_time;
                    echo '</td></tr>';
                }
                ?>
```

Only the m_content gets this error: Why is it the only one? And how do I solve this?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$m_content

Filename: views/specific_message.php

Line Number: 48
```

Here is my Controller:

```
function showSpecific(){

    $this->load->model('messages_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->messages_model->getMessages();

    $data['main_content'] = 'specific_message';
    $this->load->view('includes/login_template', $data);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `var_dump($query->result())` and see what is problem with m_content. Another suggestion is dont use mysql queries inside view files, use them only for templating

Comment: do you get other values printed ?

Comment: Yes all the other values get printed. The query is inside of a model, sorry i forgot to copy that line of the code as well. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try and answer again then. Thanks!

Comment: Even if $data['query'] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->query("...");
```

should be

```
$query=$this->db->query("...");
```

so you can

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {...}
```

**reference:** [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

**After question Update :** You have $query variable inside your view because of $data['query'] ($data will be extracted), $query is your object now (inside your view) so you can loop the $query.

Wrong model name **getMessages()** has been called, it should be **showSpecific()**

Comment: I changed it and all corresponding places but now I get the following error:    
    Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array in /htdocs/findjou/application/controllers/messages.php on line 19

Comment: Are you using array notation anywhere ? i.e $row['u_id'] ? because it's returning an object so use it like $row->u_id;

Comment: Yes I do(did). I updatet my original post with my original controller, right now in my editor it is changed as you mentioned. (After I changed it the new error came.)

Comment: You are calling getMessages(); function but in your example you've showSpecific(), do you have getMessages() function in your model, also your controller name is  showSpecific()?

Comment: Ohh man, that was it! I called the wrong model function. By the way, is it bad practice to name the controller and the model function the same? Thanks you so much! I tried to vote your answer as useful but it tells me I need 15 reputation first. How can I else vote for you to say thanks?

Comment: I think it is confusing so why should you do that!

Comment: Thanks ! I can understand your limitations that you can't vote me up but it's ok. :-)

Comment: You're right, I will give them other names in the future :-) Ok :-) I'll vote for you when I have reached the level! :-)