# CodeIgniter: Undefined property: stdClass::$date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date-format

I'm experiencing a serious problem when I'm trying to make my CodeIgniter model comunicate with database properly.

In the answer I found [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792814/codeigniter-message-undefined-property-stdclass) I read that I shouldn't make queries like this:

```
            $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT patient_id FROM visits
                          WHERE date LIKE DATE_FORMAT('$row->date', '%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY date");
```

but like that:

```
$this->db->select('patient_id');
$this->db->from('visits');
$this->db->like('date', "DATE_FORMAT($row->date, '%Y-%m-%d')");
```

Although, still can't figure out how to make it work. I'm also not sure if I used $this->db->like properly.

Comment: What's your previous query? Are you sere there's a 'date' row, and that you returned an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to call:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

to get the results. Also, you dont need to $this->db each time, so your query could look like this:

```
$this->db
    ->select('patient_id')
    ->from('visits')
    ->like('date', "DATE_FORMAT($row->date, '%Y-%m-%d')", FALSE); 
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You need to pass FALSE as 3rd argument in the like() call, or the whole query expression will be escaped and compared as is

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! :) That's actually nice and clean solution. And definitely easier to read. Sometimes you just need another brain ;) Thanks again!