# Undefined property when extending CI_Model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter Message: Undefined property: stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792814/codeigniter-message-undefined-property-stdclass)

location: **application/core/student_model.php**

```
class Student_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

location: **application/controllers/test.php**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Student_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $student = $this->student_model->setId('1234567');
        echo $student->getId();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following message/error.

```
Message: Undefined property: Test::$student_model
Filename: controllers/test.php
Line Number: 13
```

This line is where I am calling the method setId.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
$this->student_model->setId('1234567');
```

with

```
$this->Student_model->setId('1234567');
```

Your class is capitalized, so the property should also be capitalized afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Student_model', 's_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $student = $this->s_model->setId('1234567');
    echo $student->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong is :

you are assigning `$student`  to  `$this->student_model->setId('1234567');`
which is a function or 'setter' that does not return anything;  and you won't be able to use `$student->getId();`

what I would do is that

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('student_model', 'student');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->student->setId('1234567');
        echo $this->student->getId();
    }
}
```